# show windows kernel memory

Tags: windows, memory, kernel

Is there a command-line tool that shows the Kernel Memory (and will let me redirect the output)? (Win2K and XP, at least)

The task manager shows it on the main page (Total, Paged and Nonpaged), but you can't capture those values into a file.

pmon shows it happily, but its a repeating tool and, frustratingly, you can't pipe it into a file.

SysInternals pslist shows NP mem for every process but NOT the system.

Comment: I forgot to add, I tried poolmon too (after jumping through the gtflags hoops) but it seemed to behave like pmon. And "unknown switch: n" when I tried poolmon /n abc.log

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for this too...

Answer (score 1):

What about PoolMon.exe from [Microsoft Windows Support Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326)? It has got a /n Switch that lets you redirect output into a file. (but not every version of it)

With support tools from W2k3 it works (even under WinXP).

Don't forget to use Gflags.exe in order to enable pool tagging.

Comment: Nice find, can you provide a link to the tool you mentioned?

Comment: Just visit microsoft and search for "windows support tools". Then you should search for your windows version.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=windows+support+tools&form=dlc

Comment: My comment was meant as a hint so you could improve your answer